# Close modal window JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have page with products. 
When adding a product to the shopping cart a modal window is fired up for confirmation - this can take up to 2 seconds.

I  want to show another modal window just before the confirmation modal to show "loading..."

my problem is that I don't know how to close the "loading..." modal when the 'confirmation' modal is appear.

This the code which fired up the confirmation modal:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var $dialog = $('<div style="background-color:red"></div>')
        .html('<h1>loading...</h1>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'loading...'
        });
        $('.AddToCartButton').click(function () {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        });        

    });
```

On the 'confirmation' modal I am trying to close the the 'loading..." modal with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#AddToCartButton').dialog('close');    
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: AddToCartButton is id or class

Comment: post your html code related to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a class in the function:

```
$('.AddToCartButton')
```

and an ID in the script tag:

```
$('#AddToCartButton')
```

Change them both to the same type.